# How can I output segmentation results of different colors for the same label when doing instance segmentation?

Tags: python

When I was doing instance segmentation, I only marked one label, and then the output result after the training was completed had only one color.
I want the results of segmenting objects with the same label to have different colors. What should I do?

Comment: For example, in YOLOv8, I tried to modify the prompt.py file and plotting.py file, but they did not achieve the results I wanted. I don’t know where to modify them.